# What does: Error Broken count >0 mean?

Tags: package-management

I have the message:

```
Error Broken count >0
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Details: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
firefox-globalmenu: Depends: firefox (= 19.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) but 19.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is installed
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the message says, you might have bad repositories. You can either remove them, or remove all repositories and only keep the default ones.

Run:

`gksu software-properties-gtk`

This will open the software sources dialog. Click on "Other Software" and remove all  third party repositories.

[image: will be like this]

After that, run this command and see if the problem has been solved:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Mahmoud20070 thanks. I think the problem is solved!

Comment: answer fixed my problem u a star

Answer (score 32):

Just click on forbidden Icon on top bar, select "Show updates" and follow screen instructions:

[image]

by right-click on it, this error message written in it:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click
>   menu or apt-get in a teminal to see what is wrong. The error message
>   was :'Error:BrokenCount>0'. This usually means that your installed
>   packages have unment dependences

Also you can use command instead: `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`

Comment: This fixed my problem. I was able to locate exactly what package was causing the trouble and removed it. Then problem solved.

Comment: Using ...-fix-broken no does not work on Ubuntu Mate 22.04.01 LTS

Answer (score 3):

**Run this in the terminal**

> This solved the issue

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

If you have installed Synaptic Package manager then simply filter the broken packages and mark for complete removal. And then hit apply!

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal and type `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Check if you see an error similar to:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'
to correct the problem.
```

It means that the upgrade was halted midway. You need to complete the upgrade manually by typing the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If the error is something like:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?
```

In this case, the upgrade process was unable to remove its lock file before exiting. Let's remove the lock files and try again:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Now, type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That's it. You should be good to go now.