# Update package broken

Tags: updates

Error BrokenCount > 0

Details refer to lib6 dependencies
I had attempted to up grade from 12.04 to 14.04 but the upgrade package advised me
not to because my graphics hardware might not be good enough. After I didn't continue
the system upgrade, the Broken package message appears in Update Manager.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/263460/what-does-error-broken-count-0-mean