# I got an Error and my computer screen is twitching and all jumpy -Help?-

Tags: 14.04, error-handling

The error massage was:'

```
Error:BrokenCount>0'.
```

it said that

> "this usually means that your installed packages have unmet
>   dependencies."

What to do??!?!

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, logging in as your user, and running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -f`. You can get back to the GUI by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the repo sources are up to date and not broken:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*     #remove repo cache
sudo apt-get update                  #renew repo cache
```

Try to Install the package again.

```
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

Once the package determines that you have some missing dependencies, run the following command to fix broken or missing dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Above command will only download the missing dependencies if you have already installed the package.

Comment: Hi there , i did what you said and the computer stopped jumping but the error sign was still there so i restarted the comp. When i restarted it , the icons became realy big and the crouser and the keyboard stopped working. What can i do? Please help me im lost.

Comment: This might help to fix the error message:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/263460/what-does-error-broken-count-0-mean

Comment: Were you trying to do a distro-update? Or what kind of packages were you installing?  ...

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote me to do and it looked all fine until i restarted the computer:/

Comment: Were you trying to do a distro-update? Or what kind of packages were you installing? ...