# How to fix software updater packages broken?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I have this trouble in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

[image] [image]

I don't know how to fix this. Why this problem happened? Please everybody help.

Comment: Can you edit your question and give the output of `sudo apt-get update`?  That should show what repositories are failing.

Comment: I try like you said: but this happen: http://imgur.com/7itxov8. what next?

Comment: That looks like the CD (Xenial 16.04) has become part of your repositories which would mean that you would have to leave it in all the time.  I believe that if you go to your `Software & Updates` under the `Other Software` tab, take the check mark out from in front of any that start with `CDROM:` that should fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does: Error Broken count >0 mean?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263460/what-does-error-broken-count-0-mean)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and [this](http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/184249#.V1K85kqLRNw) solution worked for me:

```
sudo su
mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
mv /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/available-bad
cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install -f
```

Hope it works also for you!