# Unable to update or remove software (new install)

Tags: permissions, updates

I'm new to Ubuntu, so please be gentle.

I tried to update the OS through the software centre, but got an internal error. I restarted and then tried to update again. Nothing will update or be removed. There's an error message saying `Error: BrokenCount > 0`.

I've searched for this on this site, and [followed the instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263460/what-does-error-broken-count-0-mean) of the top answer: `gksu software-properties-gtk`. However, I don't have the program installed that is needed. When I try to install it with `sudo apt install gksu` I get errors about unmet dependencies. When I follow the advice to type `apt-get -f install` I get messages about permission being denied and asking if I'm the root. (I've included a picture of the terminal)

The common theme - from my own computer and other posts on here - is that it's problems with third party repositories. I only installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS last night. The only program I installed was PlayOnLinux.

Like I said - I'm a total noob. All the commands above I got from the internet. I have no idea how to do anything.

[image]

Comment: Use `sudo -H` instead of `gksu` in your first command. For the last one, use `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: @Zanna Thank you very much for helping a lost soul.

Comment: Did you manage? :) if you fixed it, could you perhaps write an answer explaining how? If not, please edit your question so we know what is still not working

Comment: @Zanna It worked perfectly. Thank you! I have written an answer as you suggested. Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

As Zanna suggested, I used

`sudo -H software-properties-gtk`

instead of

`gksu software-properties-gtk`

When I did that, it opened the window shown in [the top answer of the post I linked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263460/what-does-error-broken-count-0-mean) to. I then followed their instructions:

- I went to "other software" tab,
- Selected and removed all of the third party repositories,
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get update`,
- Losts of code scrolled through the terminal window,
- I restarted my machine - not sure if necessary,
- I went back to the Ubuntu Software and clicked install - they installed.

All updates were then successful.

Comment: You can also accept your own answer, that way people scrolling through search results will see that the issue has been resolved.